# Can't stop apps from auto startup

Tags: 20.04, gnome, startup, startup-applications

I've been having this problem a while (20.04). Specifically with Bluemail and Mattermost, they open up one I boot the device automatically. I've looked at startup applications and they are not listed. Is there another way to stop this?

Answer (score 3):

Autostarting programs have a .desktop launcher under `~/.config/autostart` or `/etc/xdg/autostart`. These in `autostart` contain a directive `NoDisplay=true`, which causes them not to be displayed in the tool "Startup Applications".

It would appear that these programs also have launchers in either of these folders, that are set not to display. So inspect the .desktop launchers in these folders, and move the ones related to these applications out.

Then again, next time you launch the application, they may (or may not) automatically recreate such desktop launcher. Then you will need to leave the launcher in place. However, you can edit these launchers and add the directive `X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=false` (Gnome only) or `Hidden=true` (any desktop).

If the file is in the system directory, copy it to `~/.config/autostart` and edit the copy: it overrules the systemwide copy.

If the application persists, and resets the file each time (sigh!!!), set the launcher read only after having modified it.

Comment: Thanks so much for your help. I couldn't find .desktop launchers for either of the specific applications in either ~/.config/autostart or /etc/xdg/autostart. However I did find a snap-userd-autostart.desktop file which is a "Helper program for launching snap applications that are configured to start automatically." and disabled it. It seems to have worked. As far as I can tell, this just means that in the future none of my snap applications will autostart? (which was my goal anyway).

Comment: You isolated the problem successfully to snap. Probably, snap has its own autostart folders, and you will then find the specific desktop files there. I do not run snap myself. Can you provide the output of `printenv XDG_DATA_DIRS`? I could then include the path for snaps as well in my answer. Rather than entirely disabling snap autostart, disabling for specific applications would be a more correct approach.

Comment: it returns /usr/share/ubuntu:/usr/local/share/:/usr/share/:/var/lib/snapd/desktop

Comment: Thank you for pointing out about Hidden=true.

Answer (score 0):

Same here, same problem with Bluemail for years. I asked them to allow disabling it & have an option to close the app & actually end the Bluemail process, not keep running in background. No response.
So my messy solution has been to kill Bluemail with the System Monitor when I don't need it & only reboot if I need to. (I know this is not a good solution because it could leave crap lying around, but works for me).
It's snap/bluemail that should sort it.