# Startup applications not loyal to actual configuration

Tags: 22.04, startup, autostart, startup-applications

Some programs running at startup (such as skype) are not listed in the startup application from Ubuntu 22.04. I have been following [this other question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1388678/cant-stop-apps-from-auto-startup) but I do not have  `~/.config/autostart` or `/etc/xdg/autostart` to edit. How do I remove some of those softwares and avoid them running at startup?

Also, is there a way to add other programs (such as Slack) to start without me knowing where their `bin` is located?